# Get changed fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have `ui-grid` and doing some edits in it, so `data` binded into grid has that changes. What is good solution to push changed data back to server? I think best is to get only changed row, or even changed fields. How I can achieve this in AngularJs

Answer (score 0):

look at

`$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
          //set gridApi on scope
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue ;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
        };`

You can easily attach any ajax call here.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

Comment: i never used moongoose in angular , only in pure node.js application, but in theory you can wrap any (really any) method inside $Q promise. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. It does not depends if its rest call or moongose insert/update